# Can't figure out error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, logging

I'm trying to get google glog to work with windows, but I get these errors that I can't figure out.

```
// Variables of type LogSeverity are widely taken to lie in the range
// [0, NUM_SEVERITIES-1].  Be careful to preserve this assumption if
// you ever need to change their values or add a new severity.
typedef int LogSeverity;

const int INFO = 0;
const int WARNING = 1; 
const int ERROR = 2;
const int FATAL = 3;
const int NUM_SEVERITIES = 4;


1>c:\users\<me>\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\sampleproj\sampleproj\src\windows\glog\log_severity.h(53) : warning C4091: '' : ignored on left of 'const int' when no variable is declared
1>c:\users\<me>\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\sampleproj\sampleproj\src\windows\glog\log_severity.h(53) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'constant'
1>c:\users\<me>\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\sampleproj\sampleproj\src\windows\glog\log_severity.h(53) : error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
```

Comment: The error is in the part of your program that that you aren't showing us. Please provide a minimal, complete, program that demonstrates the error. For information about why this important and how to do it, see http://sscce.org/.

Comment: The code as presented in the question is fine. You're probably missing a semicolon somewhere before the `typedef int LogSeverity;` line. See if there's a missing semicolon before the `typedef` in the `log_severity.h` and in all the files that are included by `log_severity.h`.

Comment: I was working with just a basic windows project (just writing hello world) but you must be right. I created an empty project and it seems to work. Odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake should be somewhere else, maybe in a previous header?

The code you posted compiles without problems: http://ideone.com/Wf64q

Answer (score 2):

The code you *don't* show has this line:

```
#define INFO 0
```

This means that the code you did show is seen by the compiler as this:

```
const int 0 = 0;
```

which, of course, won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

Your identifiers are conflicting with some macro names defined somewhere else. You have probably included some Windows header file that already defines a macro with such name.